# How to fix a package that is broken or not fully installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, upgrade, dpkg

After running `apt update && apt upgrade -y` on an virtual machine,
I am getting the following error for `libssl1.1:amd64`.

```
dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.2) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...done.
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...done.
Checking init scripts...
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libssl1.1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.1:amd64

dpkg-reconfigure libssl1.1:amd64
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: libssl1.1:amd64 is broken or not fully installed
```

Here is my server information,

```
uname -a
Linux remote 4.15.0-1040-aws #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 17 13:47:10 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

This is a vital package to any Linux distribution, I cannot simply uninstall it and then reinstall it, i.e., `apt remove libssl1.1 && apt install libssl1.1`

Also, this is what is returned by `--reinstall`.

```
apt install --reinstall libssl1.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.1:amd64
```

**Bug Report**

> installed libssl1.1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10 --https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1832919

Comment: Yes you can. Apt will reinstall using a single command (no need to uninstall): `sudo apt install --reinstall libssl1.1`

Comment: Possible: According to [bug LP:#1495302](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1495302) look for a dialog box during the install/reinstall. Avoid use of the '-y' flag.

Comment: By uninstall and reinstall I mean, `apt remove ...` and `apt install ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround from the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1832919),

```sh
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libc6
sudo dpkg --configure libssl1.1
```