# Can't install, "error processing package"

Tags: apt, system-installation

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libimage-magick-perl imagemagick libopenexr-dev libopenexr25
  libmagick++-6.q16-8 libpostproc55 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libswscale-dev
  libavcodec58 libimage-magick-q16-perl libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libpython2.7
  libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  libavutil-dev libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common libavformat58
  libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib
  libswresample-dev libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  apport apport-gtk dpkg dpkg-dev libdpkg-perl python3-apport
  python3-problem-report
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up gdm3 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix a package that is broken or not fully installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151995/how-to-fix-a-package-that-is-broken-or-not-fully-installed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10 for libpaper1:amd64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241362/fix-package-post-installation-script-subprocess-returned-error-exit-status-10-fo)

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove